# Django Templates: How about just "load" and "load * from" in performance?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have many templatetags in use. I just want to comfirm that `{% load mytag1 mytag2 from alltags %}` is faster than `{% load alltags %}`. In fact, I don't use all of functions in `alltags`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases `load` will load the whole template library module (via [get_library](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/base.py#L1288) function), so I guess that using one or another has no impact on performance.

Using `load mytag1 mytag2 from alltags` is usable to avoid collisions when same tag name exists in more than one template library or for readability.

Source code for `load` templatetag and `Parser`:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaulttags.py#L999

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/base.py#L345

Comment: I think you are confused here. `mytag1` and `mytag2` are not actually filters or custom tags, they are actual tag libraries. And the question is whether loading all libraries has performance benefit over loading those which are required. Or may be I have taken you wrong.

Comment: From the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#load): _You can also selectively load **individual filters or tags** from a library, using the **from** argument._

Comment: I do not get it why would you give a name to template library so that it looks like it is a tags: ie: mytag1.

I do not believe you can load library using ``load`` with ``from`` keyword.

Comment: `load ... from ...` may even be slower, since it looks like it has to build a temporary tag library. But, the difference is almost certainly irrelevant. This is not the first place you should be looking if you think you have performance problems.

Comment: @Bob, I agree. _from_ keyword is there to avoid collisions when same tag name exists in more than one template library or for readability.